# Cassandra major compaction for leveled compaction column family

Tags: cassandra

What happens when I perform a Major compaction on a column family with the Leveled compaction configured with **nodetool compact**  ?

[Documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/nodetool#nodetool-compact) says:

> compact [keyspace][cf_name]
>
> For column families that use the SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, initiates an immediate major compaction of all column families in keyspace. For each column family in keyspace, this compacts all existing SSTables into a single SSTable. This can cause considerable disk I/O and can temporarily cause up to twice as much disk space to be used. Optionally takes a list of column family names.

This one is related to Tiered compaction. What about Leveled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a major compaction for LCS.  `nodetool compact` will invoke the next minor compaction and is thus only useful if you've disabled automatic compaction for increased manual control.

Comment: Might be worth updating the post since Cassandra has major compaction for LCS since 2.2.x (or something close to that). :)

Answer (score 5):

Major compaction for LCS has been introduced since Cassandra 2.2 with the following JIRA ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7272

But I have never tested it and the manual of `nodetool compact` from DataStax doesn't describe LCS as of now so I'm not sure if it is actually useful or not.

Comment: Related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422062/major-compaction-on-lcs